# ASP.NET Repeater not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have issues.

One of them is this one.

I'm trying to bind a list of Hyperlinks to a repeater and I think my code looks all good, but my repeater is sadly lacking in anything. It's totally blank (Apart from the header, which is not databound).

I can't see where the problem is, so I'm hoping you guys can point it out to me.

Code:

**Markup**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlNavMenu"  class="navigation" runat="server" Visible="true">
<div class="search-textbox"><div>

                   <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" class="Search-Icon"
                        BackColor="White"  runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/Mobile/mobile-search-icon.png" />

                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="Search" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Enter keyword or product code'; isSet=true; }"
                        onmouseover="if(this.value == 'Enter keyword or product code') { this.value='';isSet = true; }"
                        onmouseout="if(this.value == '' && !isSet) { this.value='Enter keyword or product code'; isSet=>false; }"
                        MaxLength="255" Text="Enter keyword or product code" ontextchanged="btnSearch_Click"/>

                   <asp:ImageButton ID="btnClear" class="Search-Cancel" BackColor="White" runat="server" OnClick="btnClear_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/Mobile/mobile-search-cancel.png" />

                    </div>
                    </div>

                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlComputers" runat="server" CssClass="nav-item" Visible="true">

                    <asp:Label id="lblComp" Text="Computers" runat="server" cssclass="Menu-Panel-Header"></asp:Label>

            <asp:Repeater ID="rptComputers" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink ID="hlCompCategories" runat="server" CssClass="nav-sub-item"><%#Eval("XW_WEBCATNAME") %></asp:HyperLink></ItemTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater> 

           </asp:Panel

            <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pnlComputers" CollapsedSize="64" ExpandedSize="192" Collapsed="True" ExpandControlID="lblComp" CollapseControlID="lblComp" AutoCollapse="false" AutoExpand="False" ScrollContents="True" ExpandDirection="Vertical" />

             </asp:Panel>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Customer"] is GPCUser)
    {
        hlLogInOut.Text = "Log Out";
        hlLogInOut.NavigateUrl = "log-in.aspx?logout=1";
        hlRegDetails.Text = "My Details";
        hlRegDetails.NavigateUrl = "/update-details.aspx";
    }
    else
    {
        hlLogInOut.Text = "Log in";
        hlLogInOut.NavigateUrl = "/log-in.aspx";
        hlRegDetails.Text = "Register";
        hlRegDetails.NavigateUrl = "/create-account.aspx";
    }

    BindCategories();
}


private void BindCategories()
{



    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();

            DataTable Data = new DataTable();


            connect.ConnectionString = "SERVER = SERVER-SQL01; Trusted_Connection=yes; DATABASE=PCSQL";
            connect.Open();

            string query = null;

            query = "SELECT * from dbo.STOCK_GROUPS WHERE XW_MAINGROUP = '1' ORDER BY XW_WEBCATNAME ASC";

            SqlDataAdapter command = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connect);
            command.Fill(Data);
            connect.Close();

            rptComputers.DataSource = Data;



        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEX)
        {
            sqlEX.ToString();
        }
    }

}

protected void rptComputers_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HyperLink hlCompCategories = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hlCompCategories");

        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        hlCompCategories.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/" + "Computers" + "/" + dr["XW_URL"] + "/index.aspx");

        if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dr["xw_webcatname"], System.DBNull.Value)))
        {
            hlCompCategories.Text = (dr["xw_webcatname"]).ToString();
            hlCompCategories.ToolTip = (dr["xw_webcatname"]).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            hlCompCategories.Text = dr["groupname"].ToString();
            hlCompCategories.ToolTip = dr["xw_webcatname"].ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure that the issue is in the ItemDataBound method because the rest of the panel loads fine (search bar and header, etc.) but none of my links are there.

Comment: Did you use a debugger? what did you see there? (Are you getting into `rptComputers_ItemDataBound`?)

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger doesn't work on this website. My boss (who coded the site himself almost ten years ago and has only done sporadic updates since)  tells me it's due to the way every page links with both SQL and MYOB and several other bits and pieces through APIs and the debugger can't reference them properly but I don't know enough to know if that's true. I just have to refresh Chrome to check if something works. It's for a mobile page anyway so I'm checking on my S5.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: My bad, it's old habits from sending internal emails around a company where most of the senior employees will get themselves in a sphincter-crunch if you forget your place.

Answer (score 2):

After

```
rptComputers.DataSource = Data;
```

add

```
rptComputers.DataBind();
```

Otherwise it won't bind.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Really earning my wages here. Thanks for pointing that out but I'm still having the issue where my repeater has no items in it?

Comment: Run your query directly against the database. Make sure the results aren't empty.

Comment: Query returns the correct results if I run it in the SQL Manager.

Comment: @ChrisHinton Then make sure that `rptComputers.DataSource = Data;` is getting reached and that `Data` contains >0 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing `AutoEventWireup=true` in Page header in aspx file.

If not than please try to bind the repeater in the `Page_Load` event instead binding in `Page_Init` event.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work. I have the AutoEventWireup=true and have moved bindCategoires() to the page load event but sadly nothing changed.